# Outlook plugin to create new folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, plugins, microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm looking for an outlook plugin (preferably free) that will allow me to select a bunch of message, then right-click and "Move to New Folder", which would allow me to create a new folder with the name and location of my choosing, then move the selected messages there.

Does anyone know of a tool that can do this?

Comment: Why don't you just create a new outlook mail folder which will do exactly same thing...rather than seeking some unecessary plug-in.

Comment: I don't think MAW has actually tried to use Outlook 2013, or doesn't know the navigation since the feature is already there by default. The issue with trying to create a Move to New Folder is that you don't have an easy of stating where the new folder should be placed.

Comment: @Immanual -Because I"m trying to file a large number of emails into folders based on their internal job number, your method is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a plug-in. The navigation is as follows:

- You select your messages, right click > Move > Other Folder
- Click New (folder)
- Name your new folder
- Select the new folder
- Click OK